# Activate button after checking the password in input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a form in which I have input for password and button which must enable if the password from input is correct.

Here's the code I already have:

```
<form>
    <label for="password"><input type="password" name="password" size="15" id="password" onkeyup="activateBtn()" /></label>
    <input type="submit" id='delete' class='delete' disabled name="delete" value='Reset' onclick="resetFunc()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function activateBtn() {
       pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
        if (pass = "1917"){
            document.getElementById('password').onkeyup = function(){
                document.getElementById('delete').disabled = false;
        }
    }}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resetFunc(){
        countDownDate = new Date(); localStorage.setItem('startDate', countDownDate);
    }
</script>
```

At this moment the button activates whatever is typed in input space.

Comment: `pass = "1917"` is assignment, `pass == "1917"` is conditional

Comment: It might work against my wife if the HTML document is on the local network, but please don't do security on the client side, especially with the password clearly spelt out in the code.

Comment: Thank you, so much :) and yes, it is only locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used single equal to operator.

Please update the code with == instead of '='

```js
function activateBtn() {
pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
console.log(pass);
document.getElementById('delete').disabled = pass !== '1917';
}
function resetFunc(){
countDownDate = new Date(); localStorage.setItem('startDate', countDownDate);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="password"><input type="password" name="password" size="15" id="password" onkeyup="activateBtn()" /></label>
  <input type="submit" id='delete' class='delete' disabled name="delete" value='Reset' onclick="resetFunc()" />
</form>
```

Comment: And how can I redirect to another page after my reset function? Because it goes to the URL with this password in name and then the button is disabled? I mean I would like to go to for example index.php after clicking the reset button and doing the resetFunc()

Answer (score 0):

`if (pass = "1917"){` should be `if (pass == "1917"){`

Answer (score 0):

The code `if (pass = "1917")` isn't comparing, it's setting. (Although that would be truthy.)

```js
const txtPassword = document.getElementById('password');
const btnDelete = document.getElementById('delete');

txtPassword.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
 btnDelete.disabled = e.target.value !== '1917';
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input id="password" type="password">
  <input id="delete" type="submit" value="Delete" disabled>
</form>
```